# How can other libraries be invoked from chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/MeetTheModules.html it says:

> composer-client and composer-admin are the two modules that provide APIs for applications. node.js applications should only use APIs that come from these modules. If there are other APIs that are need please contact us.

If I had chaincode which needed to call out to an AWS service using the [AWS Node SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) for instance, is this one of the scenarios where we should contact the dev team?  I'm new to node.js btw, so apologies if this is an obvious question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chaincode (or transaction processor functions in Composer terms) are executed in a JavaScript virtual machine written in Go, not Node.js. It is currently not possible to import Node.js modules from a transaction processor function or call out to an external service.
We are very interested in adding Node.js chaincode support to Fabric, this is work we are planning on starting.